# Laravel no puede declarar una clase porque está en uso

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy cambiando de base de datos, de mysql a postgresql, al hacer la  php artisan migrate me dice que laravel no puede declara la clase porque el nombre ya se encuentra en uso.  Cómo puedo hacer la migración de toda la base de datos?

Comment: Has probado a hacer `php artisan migrate:fresh`?

Comment: @angogi Si, mismo error.  Lo curioso es que solo mensiona la última migración que cree, no la primera que fue para crear la tabla de usuarios

Comment: Como estas cambiando la base de datos: `composer dump-autoload` y `php artisan migrate`

Comment: Orici - el error continúa, opté por eliminar esa migración a ver si ejecuta las demás

Comment: Las migraciones que tienen problema las elimino y vuelvo a crear, copiando y pegando las instrucciones

Comment: Copia y pega en la pregunta el trazo del error y las migraciones relacionadas. También qué has cambiado en la configuración de Laravel para cambiar la base de datos. También ten en cuenta que cuando cambias algo en el archivo .env, debes limpiar en cache config